# Global erroChannel service activator not invoked

Tags: spring, integration

I have written an service activator for global `errorChannel`.

```
<!-- global default exception handler--> 
<int:service-activator input-channel="errorChannel" 
      auto-startup="true" ref="defaultExeptionHandler" >
</int:service-activator>
```

Test class

```
@Test
public void testTradeAcceptanceFlow() throws Exception {
    throw new FileNotFoundException();
}
```

Since I am explicitly throwing error, I was hoping that this would get caught in the global error channel and will in turn call my handler, which it is not doing. Any idea as to why?

Answer (score 0):

An exception is wrapped to the `ErrorMessage` and sent to the global (default) `errorChannel` if you have some async handoff in your flow.

Please, see more info in the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-errorhandler).

There is a note:

> The most important thing to understand here is that the messaging-based error handling will only apply to Exceptions that are thrown by a Spring Integration task that is executing within a TaskExecutor. This does not apply to Exceptions thrown by a handler that is operating within the same thread as the sender (e.g. through a DirectChannel as described above).

Many guys are missing this standard Java `try...catch` bahaviour in the Spring Integration and try to treat everything with that `errorCnannel`.

Regarding your test-method. It is fully does not make sense and does not get deal with any Spring Integration stuff.

Comment: Thanks artem, Have got this resolved. 
Have a question on this though, I have file input adapter with an error channel, and there is exception while processing one of the file. This exception is navigated correctly to my error channel. But my other files are not read by this file input channel. Does the input adapter stops to read next file when there is error in processing one of the file?

Comment: Typically no. Need to see your config and understand environment. Maybe you have some custom `FileListFilter`, which prevents the further directory polling or you determine that exception as a critical and stop your application or that adapter and so on.

Comment: Thank you Artem for you help. A continued quesiton, if the exception is thrown back and in the service activtor, I want to have a logic which says for certian type of exception replay the message. E.g if there is an error because of Database down or something of this sort, the exception will come to error channel and I would want to replay the message for 'n' times. How do I achieve it please?

Comment: Consider to use `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain