# How to add error channel to unmarshalling transformer

Tags: spring-integration

Here is my problem.
I am getting xml message on channel

```
<int:channel id="inbound.jms.channel" />
```

I then enrich the message and add error-channel

```
<int:header-enricher input-channel="inbound.jms.channel" output-    channel="inbound.jms.enriched.channel" >
<int:error-channel ref="janus.tradeloader.exception.channel"/>
</int:header-enricher>
<int:channel id="inbound.jms.enriched.channel"/>
```

Now the unmarshaller listen to this enriched channel as below

```
<int-xml:unmarshalling-transformer unmarshaller="uc.jaxb.transformer" input-channel="inbound.jms.enriched.channel" output-channel="uc.calypso.trade.transformer.channel"/>
```

I have written an serivice activator to channel inbound.jms.enriched.channel

```
<int:service-activator input-channel="janus.tradeloader.exception.channel" method="handleGlobalException" ref="defaultExeptionHandler" >
```

I am deliberatley passing malformed xml which while unmarshalling will throw MessageFormattingException (which I can see), but this exception is not getting onto my error-channel. Can you please advise?

Comment: I have written below 
    <int:chain input-channel="inbound.jms.channel"> <int:header- enricher> <int:error-channel  value="janus.tradeloader.exception.channel"></int:error-channel>  </int:header-enricher> </int:chain>

Comment: Hi,
I have re-written this as below

    <int:channel id="inbound.jms.channel" /> 
    <int:header-enricher input-channel="inbound.jms.channel" output-    channel="inbound.jms.enriched.channel" >
     <int:error-channel ref="janus.tradeloader.exception.channel">
    </int:error-channel> 
    </int:header-enricher> 
    <int:channel id="inbound.jms.enriched.channel"/> 
    <int-xml:unmarshalling-transformer     unmarshaller="uc.jaxb.transformer" input-channel="inbound.jms.enriched.channel" output- channel="uc.calypso.trade.transformer.channel"/>

Comment: I have done this as above. Additionally I have service activator as below
    <int:service-activator input-channel="janus.tradeloader.exception.channel" method="handleGlobalException" ref="defaultExeptionHandler" />

I am getting message transformation exception which I expect to be routed to the error channel, which is not happening. Can somebody please advise?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Global erroChannel service activator not invoked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29226438/global-errochannel-service-activator-not-invoked)

Comment: Please, don't duplicate questions. You can simply edit an existing one to add more info. Or just comment there on my answer. I'll definitely can help you. But I want to understand where you are. So, it would be enough helpful to collect your challenge in the one place. See you there!

Comment: Hi Artem, Thank you for your help. Problem is, I have a requirement which unmarshals a xml file and if any error occurs while doing so, I need to route the error to application exception channel. I am posting the context file (with suggested indention) as below I am getting the file on below channnel
    <int:channel id="inbound.jms.channel" />

Comment: I then enrich the message headers as below
    <int:header-enricher input-channel="inbound.jms.channel" output-     channel="inbound.jms.enriched.channel" > 
    <int:error-channel ref="janus.tradeloader.exception.channel"/>
    </int:header-enricher> 
    <int:channel id="inbound.jms.enriched.channel"/>

Comment: Please, edit that your another question with and let me know about an edit in the comment for my answer. The code blocks in comments aren't readable. Sorry

Comment: This message is then passed for marshalling
    <int-xml:unmarshalling-transformer unmarshaller="uc.jaxb.transformer" input-channel="inbound.jms.enriched.channel" output- channel="uc.calypso.trade.transformer.channel"/>

here it throws MessageFormattingException which is supposed to go to channel janus.tradeloader.exception.channel and then call my service activators which is not happening. Can you please advise?

Comment: Hi Artem,
I have posted the problem as you suggested.

Comment: Hi Artem,
Could you please have a look at reposted question and let me know please?

Comment: I said you already: let's continue discussion in the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29226438/global-errochannel-service-activator-not-invoked. And, please, investigate the document I've referred you in that question.